# What error logging web services or apps exist that log handled and unhandled exceptions?

Tags: error-handling, custom-error-handling

I know about ELMAH, but that only logs unhandled errors. I need something that logs ALL errors (handled and unhandled). Does anyone know of such a program or service which does this? Preferably something open source that can work on any platform using any language, though I'm willing to consider other projects that are similar to ELMAH and log all errors (handled and unhandled).

FYI, I also know about log4net and that would be ideal but I hear it's very complicated and I'd like something that's simple to implement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "list of X" questions are usually closed pretty quickly here. Also, you don't want to log "all errors", as there's quite a bit of code which throws exceptions behind the scenes. A lot of that code is part of .NET.

Comment: My apologies if I have breached any rules or policies. I just couldn't find the information I was looking for anywhere else and felt this would be the best place to ask. I meant to say event rather than error. In any case, I've taken a look at NLog and it does everything I require so, to Andrew who answered below, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log4net isn't that complicated and there are tons of examples of how to use it.  another one you might consider which is a bit simpler than log4net is nlog.

i'd suggest spending a few hours trying some examples of both of these. i am sure you'll see that they are actually pretty straight forward to implement.